# Request method 'POST' not supported with Ajax/Spring MVC handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, post

I have a button that executes a POST request to my server but it doesn't work.

My application disabled csfr and I have other buttons that use $.post() and it works fine. In the discussed function it never gets to the server side.

This is the button:

```
<button onclick="honor('gold', '${loggedUser.username}')" style="margin-right: 2%;"
                class="btn btn-info pull-right">
                <span style="padding: 2em 4em;">NEXT</span>
            </button>
```

This is the honor function:

```
function honor(type, username) {
var message = $("#message").val();
var name = $("#honor-box").attr("name");
var id = name.substring(1);
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "http://(emitted)/honor?type=" + type + "&id="
            + id + "&name=" + username,
    data : message,
    dataType : "json"
});
}
```

The server side function header:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/honor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void giveHonor(Principal principal, Model model, @RequestParam(name = "type") String type,
        @RequestParam(name = "id") String id, @RequestParam(name = "name") String name,
        @RequestParam("json") String message)
```

It works when I remove data: message from honor() and remove @RequestParam("json") String message from giveHonor() so the problem is definietly there.

I need the honor() function to send the information to giveHonor() on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You received message as param. pass it as param from ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "http://(emitted)/honor?type=" + type + "&id="
            + id + "&name=" + username + "&json="+ message,
});
```

Comment: I have changed it as you suggested and now it returns the following error: Required request body is missing. In addition, as mentioned before I have disabled csfr so passing the a token won't help.